# simple 32bit floatingpoint image format?

Tags: image-processing, image-formats, hdrimages

What image formats that support 32-bit floating point values (per channel)? I would like to read and write uncompressed 32-bit RGB images in C++ as simply as possible.

There is [OpenEXR](http://www.openexr.com/), but it's rather complex and so far I didn't get the open library to work.

Then there is TIFF but LibTiff seems to have some issues with 32bit fp tiffs.

There is also Radiance .hdr which is fairly simple - but unfortunately applies some kind of lossy compression

What other image formats are there that support 32bit floats?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft HD Photo Format supports 128bpp floating point for RGB and RGBA

[HD Photo Format Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg430023%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[Native Pixel Formats Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719797%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Search for the following on the **Native Pixel Formats** page

```
GUID_WICPixelFormat128bppRGBFloat

GUID_WICPixelFormat128bppRGBAFloat
```

EDIT:

For the benefit of others who are interested in this format:

Microsoft submitted this format for standardization as [JPEG XR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_XR). In July 2010, reference software to implement the JPEG XR standard was published as [ITU-T Recommendation T.835](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=1915) and International Standard ISO/IEC 29199-5. The bitstream specification of the JPEG XR standard can be downloaded from ITU-T at http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-T.832

Key benefits of the HD Photo/ JPEG XR -

- Multiple color formats for display or print
- Fixed or floating point high dynamic range (HDR) image encoding
- Lossless or high quality lossy compression
- Extremely efficient decoding for multiple resolutions and sub-regions (The ability to decode only the information needed for any resolution or region and to manipulate the image as compressed data)
- Minimal overhead for format conversion or transformations during
  decode

Microsoft released a [Device Porting Kit (DPK)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463381) providing implementation details for encoder/decoder, including sample reference code for use with Unix/Linux platforms.

Comment: thanks for that - although i'm on windows, i should stay multiplatform though

Comment: Cheers for that overview! A while ago, I asked about JPEG-XR on MSDN forums and received similar answer, but points to older ref software package. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowswic/thread/dfdd2455-f2fc-4f51-b528-affade3374a1